# How do I append data to existing clipboard in a new format without removing the existing data?

Tags: delphi, append, delphi-xe2, clipboard

I need to put data on the clipboard in several formats, one being RTF. The component I'm using handles everything except for RTF wonderfully. How can I append the RTF format data without blowing away the data placed there already by the ancestor class? I'm trying to avoid duplicating the clipboard logic from the ancestor in my copy to clipboard routine if there's a way to do so.

Comment: You likely want to do this inside the code that currently adds to the clipboard. We can't see that.

Comment: Yeah, I can do it there, but I was hoping to not do so. This is a subclass of the Scintilla edit control (via DLL) so I'll either need to freshen up on my C++ or port the logic there into Delphi within my copy routine. I was hoping I could just do Scintilla.Copy followed by slip RTF format into clipboard. I've found nothing in my search. Perhaps it's not possible? Duplicating the Scintilla logic wouldn't be the end of the world, just an annoying chore I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Actually, perhaps you can just do, `OpenClipboard`, SetClipboardData`, `CloseClipboard` and make sure you don't call `EmptyClipboard`.

Comment: Well that would be simple. Thanks. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can append to the existing clipboard data by doing the following:

1. Call `Clipboard.Open`.
2. Call the base class method that puts the other data on the clipboard.
3. Call `Clipboard.SetAsHandle`, or `SetClipboardData` passing your RTF.
4. Call `Clipboard.Close`.

So long as the inherited call is inside your `Open/Close` pair you will get the desired effect.

Here is a demonstration of what I mean:

```
procedure SetBuffer(Format: Word; const Buffer; Size: Integer);
var
  DataPtr: Pointer;
  Data: THandle;
begin
  Data := GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE+GMEM_DDESHARE, Size);
  try
    DataPtr := GlobalLock(Data);
    try
      Move(Buffer, DataPtr^, Size);
      Win32Check(SetClipboardData(Format, Data) <> 0);
    finally
      GlobalUnlock(Data);
    end;
  except
    GlobalFree(Data);
    raise;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
const
  Text: string = 'foo';
begin
  Clipboard.Open;
  try

    // imagine this next block is the base component's method to set the clipboard 
    Clipboard.Open;
    try
      Bitmap := GetFormImage;
      try
        Clipboard.Assign(Bitmap);
      finally
        Bitmap.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Clipboard.Close;
    end;

    // once that is done, we can add out extra data    
    SetBuffer(CF_UNICODETEXT, Text[1], ByteLength(Text));
  finally
    Clipboard.Close;
  end;
end;
```

Because we hold a lock on the clipboard the whole time, no other process can get in our way. And the base component method will empty the clipboard before it starts adding its text.